# Golang: How to recover a string(int64)?

Tags: go

example:

```
var num int64
num = 1234
str := string(num)
```

How can I recover the original num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) `string(num)` yields a string with the UTF-8 representation of the rune `num`.  Use [utf8.DecodeRuneInString](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#DecodeRuneInString) to decode the rune from the string.

```
var num int64
num = 1234
str := string(num)
num2, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(str)
fmt.Println(num, num2) // prints 1234 1234
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if the num is 123456789?

Comment: @GraGURU 123456789 is not a valid Unicode code point.  Values outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to "\uFFFD".

Answer (score 0):

You do this with `strconv.Atoi` or `strconv.ParseInt`, assuming what you intend to do with `string`, judging by your comment of *what if the num is 123456789*, is to get a string representation of your number.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    num := 123456789
    str := strconv.Itoa(num)

    num2, _ := strconv.Atoi(str)
    num3, _ := strconv.ParseInt(str, 10, 64);

    fmt.Printf("str=%v num2=%v num3=%v", str, num2, num3)
}
```